# Running Tomcat service on same port as IIS Service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, iis

I'm trying to set up three services to run on the same port (port 80). Two of the services are hosted on IIS thus enabling bindings to use the same port. One of the three services is however hosted on a Tomcat server as it is a Java Servlet. How can i set this up so that all can be accessed through port 80?

I've tried using URL Rewrite in the IIS to forward the request to port 8080 where the Tomcat service is active but it doesn't work with other services being active on port 80.

Any other ideas?

EDIT

---

I have no support for URL Rewrite not working for this purpose other than my own attempts. If anyone have used it and knows it should work, please shout out as it would be an optimal solution with minimal complexity to the system!

Comment: I assume that this can be performed with haproxy if you bind a port and a specific uri to be forwarded to IIS or tomcat (dependign on your haproxy rule)

Comment: and this would work even though I have two active services listening on port 80 already? I assume the haproxy rule defines the URL? (Never worked with haproxy before so I have no idea.

Comment: You need to define rule binding to 80. Within the rule, you define 2 conditions, one that will forward to localhost:8080 for tomcat and another to iis. Should work, even if I never did it either

Comment: Thank you @aorfevre! I'll make sure to try this!